# Binary Relation (paralell)

Tags: elementary-set-theory

Prove that the relation "being parallel with" (I actually translated this myself from my native language so there is a high likelihood that I've done it wrong) is a relation of equivalence in set of all lines.

Now I know that in order for something to be a relation of equivalence it has to be transitive, symmetrical and reflexive but how to prove that?

I can see that is transitive knowing that if a and b are parallel and if b and c are parallel it must mean that a and c are parallel but I'm not sure that is really the correct way how to go with this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If your translation is correct, then indeed your argument that 'being parallel with' is transitive is correct, if you are allowed to assume standard theorems of Euclidean geometry.

Similarly, if $a$ is parallel with $b$ then $b$ is parallel with $a$ (symmetry).

One pitfall might be if a line is allowed to be parallel with itself, i.e. if you need two distinct lines $a\neq b$ for the statement '$a$ is parallel with $b$' to make sense. This depends on your definition of 'being parallel with'.

Comment: If a line is not considered to be parallel to itself, then "parallel to" wouldn't be an equivalence relation, so it is quite unlikely that the OP would be asked to prove that in a context where it isn't.

Comment: It depends on the way the question is formulated - i.e. if the original question was 'is the relation of being parallel with a binary relation'. Though from the way the stackexchange question is phrased, it seems unlikely, I took this possibility into account.